# What is the concepts of nominal and actual significance level?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

What is the concepts of nominal and actual significance level?

Although I understood these concepts about five years ago, I totally forgot the notion and cannot find that in Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Note:* I suspect that there are at least two different meanings of "actual significance level" around, but here's one that makes sense to me:

The nominal significance level is the significance level a test is designed to achieve. This is very often 5% or 1%. Now in many situations the nominal significance level can't be achieved precisely. This can happen because the distribution is discrete and doesn't allow for a precise given rejection probability, and/or because the theory behind the test is asymptotic, i.e., the nominal level is only achieved for $n\to\infty$.

Here's an example. We toss a coin 5 times and we want to test at nominal 5% level whether it's biased in favour of "heads". The probability for five times heads is 1/32<0.05, the probability for four times heads is 5/32>0.05. We can't reject for four heads because then we go beyond the nominal level, therefore we only reject for five heads, leaving us with an actual significance level of 1/32. (In fact Neyman and Pearson had the concept of a randomised test that in case of four heads would reject randomly with a certain probability chosen so that the overall rejection probability is 5% so that nominal and actual significance level are the same, but this is not very appealing.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Your answer is the bestest!

Comment: A very common reason nominal differs from actual is that some assumption used in obtaining the nominal level has been broken (independence, constant variance, a distributional assumption, etc)

Comment: @Glen_b I actually disagree. The p-value is computed relative to the null model including all its assumptions, and as such doesn't mind whether this model is actually not true. Of course all assumptions are always broken, actually there is no such thing as a real true probability anyway, but this also means that there is no such thing as an "actual p-value" that could be computed for any "really true model" in which all assumptions are broken. The concept of "actual p-value" only makes sense still assuming the H0 as it is.